# Reading/ analysing Json file with about 1TB size in Spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, bigdata, data-analysis

I would like to analyze a big data (0.9 TB after unzipping) in a cluster with 14 nodes and 39 cores (Azure HDInsight/Spark). But it's very slow. Here what I do:

1. Data is downloaded from [here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/).
2. `val data = spark.read.json(path)` ---- it crashes. Data are stored in HDFS.
3. `val rdd = sc.textFile(path)` ... then `rdd.count()` .... also crashes
4. `rdd.take(10)` , ... these are ok
5. It was not possible to unzip the file; I read it with data.json.gz

Any suggestion? How I can read it with json reader?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to manually provide schema for the json?

Comment: Do you get out of memory? What do you see in your Spark UI? And as @Daniel proposed, you can try to provide the schema when [you read JSON](https://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2016/01/30/processing-json-data-with-sparksql/)

Comment: I do get timeout error. I also have the schema but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention the size after unzipping but also say "It was not possible to unzip the file". If you are reading a compressed file from HDFS, the whole thing will be pulled into memory as it cannot be split. This could be the the lead to OOMEs.

What do you mean exactly by "it crashes"? What exception is being thrown?

Comment: I only see the size with gzip -l without unzipping locally. Not enough space to unzip it locally. it crashes after livy timeout, exactly after one hour; but I don't want to set timeout limitaion, I guess it is not really parallel computing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try loading it all as string by providing manual schema, this should ease the processing.

```
schema = t.StructType([
    t.StructField("Name", t.StringType(), True),  
    t.StructField("Age", t.StringType(), True),  
    ...
])

df = spark.read \
    .json('path-to-csv', schema=schema)
```